# PHP Exceptions rather than errors

Tags: php, error-handling, exception

Is there a way in PHP to make sure that I get Exceptions for everything rather than errors?

Using two different methods of errorhandling leaves me uncomfortable and it feels messy. I'd prefer the Exception style method as its more OO and thus fits better with my other programming experience.

Comment: please provide an example. did you mean php errors? The question should be: is it useful to catch errors...

Comment: No, I wanted to know if it was possibly to generalise to one way of error handling.

Raising an exception with the default error handler seems like the closest answer but still not ideal... but thats PHP for you ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can set the default error handler to only throw an exception. you can then handle all exceptions in your default exception handler.

See [`set_error_handler()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php)

Comment: Just to add: There is a built-in exception class for this use-case, the `ErrorException`: http://us2.php.net/manual/en/class.errorexception.php